# How to insert TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE into HSQLDB using JOOQ

Tags: java, scala, datetime, hsqldb, jooq

I am using `HSQLDB 2.4.0`, `jOOQ 3.7.1`, `Scala 2.11.7`, `Java 8`.

I am trying to insert a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` into a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column in an `HSQLDB` table:

```
sql.insertInto(MY_TABLE)
    .columns(MY_TABLE.INSERTED_ON)
    .values(java.time.OffsetDateTime.now())
    .execute()
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid datetime format
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Interesting! I do not find anything wrong here. The support for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is available since `HSQLDB 2.4.0` and the corresponding Java type is indeed `java.time.OffsetDateTime`. However, I do not know `jOOQ`. I am also wondering how come this question can a close vote and a down-vote.

Comment: I have verified that I could insert a string value if I change the column type to `varchar`...

Comment: Probably, I have found the reason. Check https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9174 which says: `For backwards compatibility reasons, we're still binding JSR 310 types as strings in most dialects, as JDBC drivers haven't adopted them immediately. There's a pending feature request to pass the JSR 310 type instead of the string:` [#9902](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9902)

Comment: I am not sure what they suggest to do. Do I have to upgrade to jOOQ 3.14?

Comment: IMHO, upgrading to the latest version of `jOOQ` would be the best bet.

Comment: rapt - Any update?

Comment: I have been trying the upgrade... unsurprisingly, there are numerous new exceptions. I will let you know tomorrow how it goes!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned at https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9174

> For backwards compatibility reasons, we're still binding JSR 310 types
> as strings in most dialects, as JDBC drivers haven't adopted them
> immediately. There's a pending feature request to pass the JSR 310
> type instead of the string: [#9902](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9902)

IMHO, upgrading to the latest version of jOOQ would be the best bet.

It's also mentioned there

> jOOQ still converts the value to a string expression like "timestamp
> with time zone '2019-09-05 15:02:14.5015411+02:00'" instead of just
> passing it to the JDBC driver.

You can try inserting `OffsetDateTime` formatted into a string conforming to the specified format and see if it works.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.nXXX");
String formatted = OffsetDateTime.now().format(formatter);
sql.insertInto(MY_TABLE)
    .columns(MY_TABLE.INSERTED_ON)
    .values(formatted)
    .execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB can convert a string into TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE only when formatted according to SQL standard. A string such as '2020-12-12 21:34:10.769000+2:00' is accepted. The output of the toString method of OffsetDateTime is slightly different and it fails.

You should be able to insert a string with the correct format.